# Python url encode/decode - Convert % escaped hexadecimal digits into string

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-unicode

For example, if I have an encoded string as:

```
url='locality=Norwood&address=138+The+Parade&region=SA&country=AU&name=Pav%C3%A9+cafe&postalCode=5067'
```

The name parameter has the characters %C3%A9 which actually implies the character é.

Hence, I would like the output to be:

```
new_url='locality=Norwood&address=138+The+Parade&region=SA&country=AU&name=Pavé+cafe&postalCode=5067'
```

I tried the following steps on a **Python terminal**:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url='locality=Norwood&address=138+The+Parade&region=SA&country=AU&name=Pav%C3%A9+cafe&postalCode=5067'
>>> new_url=urllib2.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
>>> print new_url
locality=Norwood&address=138+The+Parade&region=SA&country=AU&name=Pavé+cafe&postalCode=5067
>>>
```

However, when I tried the same thing within a **Python script** and run as myscript.py, I am getting the following stack trace:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 88: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using Python 2.6.6 and cannot switch to other versions due to work reasons.

How can I overcome this error?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
######################################################
```

**EDIT**

**I realized that I am getting the above expected output.**

**However**, I would like to convert the parameters in the new_url into a dictionary as follows. While doing so, I am not able to retain the special character 'é' in my name parameter.

```
print new_url
params_list = new_url.split("&")
print(params_list)
params_dict={}
for p in params_list:
   temp = p.split("=")
   params_dict[temp[0]] = temp[1]
print(params_dict)
```

**Outputs:**

**new_url**

locality=Norwood&address=138+The+Parade&region=SA&country=AU&name=Pavé+cafe&postalCode=5067

**params_list**

[u'locality=Norwood', u'address=138+The+Parade', u'region=SA', u'country=AU', u'name=Pav\xe9+cafe', u'postalCode=5067']

**params_dict**

{u'name': u'Pav\xe9+cafe', u'locality': u'Norwood', u'country': u'AU', u'region': u'SA', u'address': u'138+The+Parade', u'postalCode': u'5067'}

Basically ... the name is now 'Pav\xe9+cafe' as opposed to the required 'Pavé'.

How can I still retain the same special character in my params_dict?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your error. Are you sure you're using the same code in both the terminal and the script?

Comment: @machineyearning You are correct. Please check my edit for my actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`. When printing a unicode string, `__str__` is used and results in the `é` you see when printing `new_url`. However, when a list or dict is printed, `__repr__` is used, which uses `__repr__` for each object within lists and dicts. If you print the items separately, they print as you desire.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
new_url = u'name=Pavé+cafe&postalCode=5067'
print(new_url)  # name=Pavé+cafe&postalCode=5067

params_list = [s for s in new_url.split("&")]
print(params_list)  # [u'name=Pav\xe9+cafe', u'postalCode=5067']
print(params_list[0])  # name=Pavé+cafe
print(params_list[1])  # postalCode=5067

params_dict = {}
for p in params_list:
    temp = p.split("=")
    params_dict[temp[0]] = temp[1]
print(params_dict)  # {u'postalCode': u'5067', u'name': u'Pav\xe9+cafe'}
print(params_dict.values()[0])  # 5067
print(params_dict.values()[1])  # Pavé+cafe
```

One way to print the list and dict is to get their string representation, then decode them with`unicode-escape`:

```
print(str(params_list).decode('unicode-escape'))  # [u'name=Pavé+cafe', u'postalCode=5067']
print(str(params_dict).decode('unicode-escape'))  # {u'postalCode': u'5067', u'name': u'Pavé+cafe'}
```

**Note**: This is only an issue in Python 2. Python 3 prints the characters as you would expect. Also, you may want to look into [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) for parsing your URL instead of doing it manually.

```
import urlparse
new_url = u'name=Pavé+cafe&postalCode=5067'
print dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(new_url))  # {u'postalCode': u'5067', u'name': u'Pav\xe9 cafe'}
```

Comment: I think it'd also be useful to add that Python has functions to parse query strings already: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs

Comment: OP Is using Python 2.6, but I'll add the relevant library from there.

Comment: @Karin Thank you for the info on __repr__ and __str__. Instead of printing, ideally, I need to return the dictionary and save it into a file. I tried this - But the file still contains 'Pav\xe9+cafe' instead of 'Pavé+cafe'. And I don't really want to specify the dict values to be saved using params_dict.values()[0], params_dict.values()[1], etc. since I want to save the entire dictionary in a file...

Comment: Updated answer to include a way to print out the list and dict in the desired format.